# Error 424 when trying to get a value form combobox in ON Activate event

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have been trying use the value in the combo box however the combobox will be locked if the revision num > 0

it gives me an error when i put it in the ON ACTIVATE event
i got the error 424 on         `Me.txtMin_DailyDose.Value = Me.cboActive_Name.Column(1).Value`

```
 Private Sub Form_Activate()
    Me.Requery

    ' prevents user from changing the client, chemical, active name once the     
      revision number has become 1 or more
    If Me.txtRev.Value > 0 Then
        Me.cboClient_Name.Locked = True
        Me.cboChemical_Name.Locked = True
        Me.cboActive_Name.Locked = True
        Me.cboActive_Name.Requery
        Me.txtMin_DailyDose.Value = Me.cboActive_Name.Column(1).Value
        Me.txtADE_PDE.Value = Me.cboActive_Name.Column(2).Value
        Me.txtTTC.Value = Me.cboActive_Name.Column(3).Value
    End If

    End Sub
```

Is there anyway i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you requery the combobox, it looses its value (if it is unbound as it seems), and then neither column(1) has a value.

So after the requery, set the combobox to some value - or rethink your concept.

Edit:

Property `Column(n)` carries no (sub)properties, thus:

```
    Me.txtMin_DailyDose.Value = Me.cboActive_Name.Column(1)
    Me.txtADE_PDE.Value = Me.cboActive_Name.Column(2)
    Me.txtTTC.Value = Me.cboActive_Name.Column(3)
```

Comment: I have tried eliminating all requeries from the from's event but i am still getting the same error. the funny thing is that if i set the control source as cbo.column(1).value it works